Google Forms Script to save txt files on Google Drive
I need help with a script to save each response from a Google Form in a separate TXT file in my Google Drive. I'm stuck at line 3: I'm getting an error in var responses = e.values
Debug:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
onFormSubmit    @ Código.gs:3

Results Deserved:

Same Google Form -> QuestionA -> ResponseA -> ResponseA.txt on Google Drive


Same Google Form -> QuestionB -> ResponseB -> ResponseB.txt on Google Drive

Script I used:
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // To get form responses
  var responses = e.values;
  
  // Google Drive ID Folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('PASTA_ID'); 
  
  // Each Field saving in separated txt file
  for (var i = 1; i < responses.length; i++) { 
    var response = responses[i];
    
    // File name based in the field
    var fileName = "resposta_campo_" + i + ".txt";
    
    // Check if the file exists
    var existingFiles = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
    
    // If files exists, delete 
    if (existingFiles.hasNext()) {
      var existingFile = existingFiles.next();
      existingFile.setTrashed(true);  //move files to trash
    }
    
    // New file with the new information
    folder.createFile(fileName, response);
  }
}

I would greatly appreciate any help.

The TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values') shows up if the function is run in Google Apps Script. Instead, create an Installable Triggers in the Triggers tab of the project.

Further to @Saddles comment. Look at the documentation for triggers. There are two types of trigger: simple and installable. onFormSubmit is an installable trigger. There is a version for Sheets and another for Forms. I suggest that you also look at Event objects.

Related question: how to update google drive text file via google script?

You want to write responses to questions to specific text files.
For example in a given Google Form:

QuestionA -> ResponseA -> ResponseA.txt on Google Drive
QuestionB -> ResponseB -> ResponseB.txt on Google Drive

The question in how to update google drive text file via google script? is very similar to this question, though there are some key differences. Consider this answer which adapts the answer by @RyanDugan in the referenced question.
Logic

the script must be executed as an installable Sheets trigger - onFormSubmit
var questions = ["Question A", "Question B"] =- identifies the titles of specific questions and therefore is used in:

e.namedValues[questions[i]] to loop through the questions, to get the question responses, and to identify the file name.


+"\n"  creates a new line separator between each response which improves readability of the text file.


function copyResp2Txt(e) {

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  var folderId = "<<insert Folder ID>>"
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId) 
  // does folder exist
  if (folder) {
    // found matching folder
    var questions = ["Question A", "Question B"]
    for (var i=0;i<questions.length;i++){
      var content = e.namedValues[questions[i]]+"\n"
      // search for files with matching name
      var fileList = folder.getFilesByName(questions[i]);
      if (fileList.hasNext()) {
        // found matching file - append text
        var file = fileList.next();
        var combinedContent = file.getBlob().getDataAsString() + content;
        file.setContent(combinedContent);
      }
      else {
        // file not found - create new
        folder.createFile(questions[i], content);
      }
    }  
  }    
}

